# How can I share with other users a preconfigured algorithm?

Tags: qgis, algorithm

I´m creating a process in QGIS, and I make it work automatic. But, I´ve used a preconfigured algorithm in order to avoid selecting shapes every time you use the process.

So, is there any way I can share with other users, that preconfigured algorithm?

Here´s a image from the "algorithm", because i think the translation of his name is not correct.
[image: Processing Toolbox]

Comment: Have you tried making the algorithm part of a model?

Comment: yeah @Erik, i created different algorithms, and joined them in one. After that, i select the option of creating a preconfigurated algorithm, and i want to shared that preconfigurated.

Comment: All QGis-models are saved as a file, simply share this file with your colleagues.

Comment: @Erik, yeah i know that, but you´re not understanding me, because i think the translation to english from spanish of the name of that "algorithm" is no exact, so i´ll upload an image from that.

Comment: Which QGis-version are you working with?

Comment: With 2.18. But, I finally found it. They are allocated in C:\Users\User\.qgis2\processing\preconfigured .Thanks for all! @Erik

Comment: Feel free to expand your comment into a short answer, so others will find the answer more easily ;)